# How to set error score for learning curve(sklearn) for regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

My learning curve looks strange. Because error score is increasing.
I used RandomForestRegressor() as a model, and set rmse_error as cross_val_score() scoring method. I think that score(error) is decreasing is right, but in below learning curve, score is increasing. How should i change the code?

```
def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=None, cv=None,
                    n_jobs=-1, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5)):

    plt.figure()
    plt.title(title)
    if ylim is not None:
        plt.ylim(*ylim)
    plt.xlabel("Training examples")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv=cv,n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.grid()

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                 train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                 color="r")
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                 test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
         label="Training score")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
         label="Cross-validation score")

    plt.legend(loc="best")
    return plt


g = plot_learning_curve(best_RFR,"RF learning curves",X_train,Y_train,cv=10)
```

[learning curve picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYfAZ.png)

Comment: Do you suspect the problem to be in the plotting or the training? If the training, please include the code for the `learning_curve` function

Comment: I solved it by changing scoring parameter in learning_curve(). Thank you for your help ! @andersource